# Python - How to calculate the product of the an in consistent number of list?

Tags: python, list

I have a question, for example I have lists

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
c = [3,4,5,6,10,4,6,7,4,3]
d = [5,4,5,6,8,4,3,2,4,50]
```

I want to calculate the product of these four list.

Actually maybe it seems simply, we just write

```
e = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
   e.append(a[i] * b[i] * c[i] * d[i])
```

but the problem is, what if I have an in consistent number of list? sometimes I have 1 lists, 8 lists, 4 lists, or maybe 25 lists. I want to write a code that calculate the product of an in consistent number of list in same index automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your lists in a bigger list (list of lists):

```
super_list = [a, b, c, d] # add any more lists you want
```

and then:

```
result = []
for i in xrange(0, len(a)):
    p = 1
    for sub_list in super_list:
        p *= sub_list[i]
    result.append(p)
```

Comment: Many thanks, but maybe a typo 'xrange' should be 'range'

Comment: @ArifDarmawan Python 2 vs. Python 3. `xrange` is appropriate for Python 2.

Comment: @mitch I am using python 3

Comment: Sure. I'm just saying, that's why they opted for `xrange` - they are using Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` these lists and use `reduce` to multiply the elements:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
c = [3,4,5,6,10,4,6,7,4,3]
d = [5,4,5,6,8,4,3,2,4,50]

print([reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,i) for i in zip(a,b,c,d)])
```

Result:

```
[150, 288, 600, 1008, 2400, 480, 504, 336, 288, 1500]
```

If you're using Python3.x, you need `from functools import reduce` to import `reduce` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
map(lambda x: reduce(lambda y, z: y * z, x), zip(a, b, c, d))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that can be overloaded with an arbitrary number of arguments and use that to do the multiplication. Something like:

```
def list_product(*args):
  if len(args) == 0: #need at least one argument!
    return []
  arg_length = len(args[0])
  for arg in args: #make sure all arrays have the same length
    if arg_length != len(arg):
      return []

  out = []
  for i in range(0, arg_length):
    temp = 1
    for arr in args:
      temp *= arr[i]
    out.append(temp)
  return out  

print(list_product([1,2,3],[4,5,6])) 
# [4, 10, 18]
```

This has the advantage of being reusable. It seems like you may want to use this in a variety of places with a variety of arrays. Once you have this function, it's easy to use it with other arrays.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [4,5,6,7]
c = [1,2,2,1]
list_product(a,b,c) # gives [4,20,36,28]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `*args` parameter mechanism to collect all the lists into one tuple of all the lists:

```
def product_of_lists(*args):

    result = []
```

Now you have a way to call a function to do what you want.

Next, use `zip` to iterate over each value in each list, in turn. That is, `zip(a,b,c)` will produce a tuple of (a[0], b[0], c[0]), then another tuple of (a[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools.reduce#functools.reduce), b[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools.reduce#functools.reduce), c[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools.reduce#functools.reduce)), etc.

```
    for t in zip(*args):
```

Using the `*args` in this context flattens the tuple of args into a bunch of separate parameters, as though you had written `zip(args[0], args[1], ...)`.

At this point, `t` is a tuple that you need to multiply.

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools.reduce#functools.reduce) to apply a function that accumulates a value across an iterable (and tuples are iterables!). Like so:

```
functools.reduce(lambda a,b: calc(a,b), t)
```

This would apply the lambda to each pair of values: (t[0], t[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools.reduce#functools.reduce)), then (result-of-previous, t[n]), etc.

So, in your case, you can write your own lambda function to do multiplication:

```
        r = functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, t)
```

Or, you could import operator and use the operator.mul function, which does exactly this:

```
        r = functools.reduce(operator.mul, t)
```

Then capture the result:

```
        result.append(r)

    return result
```

Putting it all together:

```
import functools

def product_of_lists(*args):
    result = []
    for t in zip(*args):
        r = functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, t)
        result.append(r)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3, define a product function (useful in many cases):

```
def rp(seq):
    return 1 if len(seq)==0 else seq[0]*rp(seq[1:])
```

then compute the result directly

```
result = [rp(x) for x in zip(a,b,c,d)]
```

or by using a list of lists:

```
super_list = [a,b,c,d]
result = [rp(x) for x in zip(*super_list)]
```